# How to condition a user to fill the form than to oppen an specific site up

Tags: php, html, forms

i have a multi step form and want to condition users on specific sites on my web .
This mean i want that only after submitting my form a client in my case can see the redirected page ,

And that with a kinda tim-out for that page to . this redirected page need to show only to those people who fill the form first even when users copy the link and give that link to somebody else the link should not work or should direction in a error. i have archived the last part partly
Here is all my code :

On the form.php i have this :

```
<?php 
session_start(); $_SESSION['form_finished'] = true;

 ?>
```

On the proces.php i have this :

```
$emotion = $_POST['emotion']; 

if($emotion == 'Basic Pack') { 
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['form_finished'] = true; 
header('Location: /new/basicc.php'); 
} elseif($emotion == 'Deluxe Pack') { 
header('Location: html6.php'); 
} elseif($emotion == 'Premium Pack') { 
header('Location: html7.php'); 
}
```

and destination site in this case basicc.php' this :

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['form_finished']) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
?>
```

This code is working partly because if the user  on the form.php site if he just copy the basicc.php link on the address bar he can see the basic.php site imadtitly without having to fill the form , and i want that to condition him to do that and than the page to show up .

I hope i was clear thanks in advance

Comment: hello, from what i understand, you do not want direct access to `/new/basicc.php` and others from users who did not came from the form?

Comment: @Ghost Yes exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If proces.php is where submitting the form redirects then remove `$_SESSION['form_finished'] = true;` from form.php and keep it in proces.php only.

**ETA: For the timer:**

```
<script>
    var remainingSeconds = 600; // how many second before redirect
    function counter() {
        if (remainingSeconds == 0) { clearInterval(countdownTimer); window.open('form.php', '_SELF'); // return to form page
        } else { remainingSeconds--;  }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('counter()', 1000); // 1000 is the interval for counting down, in this case 1 second
</script>
```

In this case, you will have to add back the statement in form.php but set it to false `$_SESSION['form_finished'] = false;`

**ETA2:** Forgot to mention that you should also add `$_SESSION['form_finished'] = false;` in basicc.php.

Comment: i was so close and not proved this haha , yes its working as i wanted , but can i somehow set a timeout even for the user that fills the form so that the basicc.php link after for eg 10 min cant seen even from him just when he woudl fill the form again besides this thanks man

Comment: Sure but you will have to use Javascript for that. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: the script> opens a pop up like site i want just that it refresh the main page(form.php)  and the session to start from the 0 again based on the coundown can we do this with php somehow more sercurly  , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could just use a simple session for this case. Example:

If in your form action, if the form processing is in `process.php`. You could initialize there the session.

```
session_start();
$emotion = $_POST['emotion']; 
$_SESSION['form_finished'] = true; // set session

// then your other process etc. etc.

if($emotion == 'Basic Pack') { 
    header('Location: /new/basicc.php'); 
} elseif($emotion == 'Deluxe Pack') { 
    header('Location: html6.php'); 
} elseif($emotion == 'Premium Pack') { 
    header('Location: html7.php'); 
}
```

And then on the destination files: `/new/basicc.php` and others, check that session existence:

`/new/basicc.php` and others:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['form_finished'])) { // so after redirection check this
    //
    // hello, i came from process.php
    unset($_SESSION['form_finished']); // and then UNSET it! this is important
} else {
  echo 'not allowed'; // if this is not set, the page is directly accessed, not allowed
  exit;
}
```

Comment: it shows me the not allowed echo even after submitting the form

Comment: @NewLogo are you sure you have the `$_SESSION['form_submitted']` on `process.php`?

Comment: besides i think this method is more secure

Comment: yes but still echo on submitt where should i position the $_SESSION['form_submitted'] ? besides nice to hear from ya @Ghost

Comment: @NewLogo yeah, i think this is related to the one i answered a while back, anyways, the important thing is `$_SESSION['form_submitted']` should be present on `process.php` you could put it below the `session_start()`

Comment: Still echo answer after submitting on basicc.php @Ghost

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is that you should only use one page, no need for sessions ;)

Try to have a particular variable set to false, send your form to the server using a POST method <**form method=post**> and on your server, change this variable to true and render the same page again.

In the example below, I'm checking if the user has entered his name in the form. ;)

```
<!-- In form.php -->
<?php 
$formSubmitted = false;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST["name"])) {        
    //Do what you need to do with form data, for example:
    $name = filter_var($_POST["name"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

   //Maybe do some checks on the data (or add to database) and when successful:
    if($name != '')
    {
        $formSubmitted = true;  // Set variable to true
    }
}
?>

<?php if($formSubmitted): ?>
     Hello <?php echo $name; ?>! <!-- Show all other HTML things you want to show --> 
     <p> This is a message only for people who submitted the form! </p>
<?php else: ?>
    <form action='form.php' method='POST'>
        <input name='name' type='text'>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope it'll be useful and hopefully a different way to look at the problem. For multi-step, this could easily accommodate more variables to see which step the user is on ;)

Good luck :)

Comment: nice idea i will elaborate which way is the best thanks

Comment: Glad to help ;) 

If you need help with this approach, just let me know ;)